# Encoding error in PHP with Google Translate

Tags: php, encoding, machine-translation

I have some text which I need to translate into Japanese.

```
Translate text, webpage, or document
```

Google Translate returns the string as:

```
翻訳テキスト、 Webページ、またはドキュメント
```

When I am writing that text to a file (ja.po), it looks like:

```
–|–óƒeƒLƒXƒgA Webƒy[ƒWA‚Ü‚½‚ÍƒhƒLƒ…ƒƒ“ƒg
```

What would be the error?

I am using **poeditor.exe** to view the file. I am not using any encoding function at present.

```
for(/*extracting from the trnslated string array*/)
{
    $pattern = "/msgid \"".preg_quote($id, '/')."\"(\r?\n)msgstr \"\"/";
    $string = str_replace('"', '\"', $string);
    $replacement = "msgid \"$id\"\nmsgstr \"". $string . "\"";
    $res = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $con);
    $con = $res;
}
file_put_contents("ja.po", $con);
```

Comment: Are you opening the file with an editor which supports UTF-8 ? And/or with a font that supports UTF-8 ? If yes, how are you writing the string (which looks fine) to the file (which doesn't look so nice) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting the string from Google and how are you writing it? Somewhere along the way it gets converted from UTF8 to latin1 I suppose. If you can figure out where it happens, use [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to fix it.

BTW, the translated Japanese is pretty bad. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the program you are using to read that file isn't understanding the encoding format that you wrote it out as. Are you using UTF8 all the way through? Maybe try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php to convert it to UTF8 if it is some other encoding.